# Json parser without json library

Tags: java

I need to make a json parser without json library. The input will be like `{:[{}, {}]}`.  It should return 1 if string is ok and -1  if string is wrong.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the update. I had been wondering what you were working on. In the meantime, you should review [ask]

Comment: Its just a online coding kind of thing. Just help me if you can. I have written part of the code  using charAt and loo wif if else case

Comment: You should post the code with an explanation of expected inputs and outputs. Describe how it fails with any error messages or stacktraces.